# Allowing deepcopy for a C++ object that has vector of pointers to another object in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, oop, pybind11

I have two classes defined in C++:

```
class Pet {
public:
    Pet(std::string &name) : name(name) {}
    void set_name(std::string &name_) { name = name_;}
    std::string &get_name () { return name; }
private:
    std::string name;
};

class Zoo {
public:
    Zoo() {}
    void set_pets(std::vector<Pet*>& pets_) {pets = pets_;}
    std::vector<Pet*>& get_pets () {return pets;}

    // copy constructor
    Zoo(Zoo& new_zoo){
        std::vector<Pet*> new_pets;
        for ( auto& t : new_zoo.get_pets()){
            Pet new_pet(t->get_name());
            new_pets.push_back(&new_pet);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Pet*> pets;
};
```

with bindings:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    py::class_<Pet>(m, "Pet")
        .def(py::init<std::string &>())
        .def("set_name", &Pet::set_name)
        .def("get_name", &Pet::get_name)
        .def_property("name", &Pet::get_name, &Pet::set_name)
        .def("__repr__",
             [](Pet &a){
                return "<example.Pet named '" + a.get_name() + "'>";
             })
        ;
    py::class_<Zoo>(m, "Zoo")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("set_pets", &Zoo::set_pets)
        .def("get_pets", &Zoo::get_pets)
        .def_property("pets", &Zoo::get_pets, &Zoo::set_pets)
        .def("__deepcopy__",
             [](Zoo &a){
                Zoo b = a;
                return b;
             })
        ;
}
```

This is basically my attempt to implement `__deepcopy__` for the zoo object, such that I can create another zoo object on the python side, with the stuff the pointers in the pets vector copied to another memory location. My goal is to be able to allow for:

```py
import copy
from build.example import Pet
from build.example import Zoo

p1 = Pet("Molly")
p2 = Pet("Charley")
z = Zoo()
z.set_pets([p1, p2])
z2 = copy.deepcopy(z)
```

so that, if I then do

```py
p1.name = "Foo"
```

the name of the first pet in `z` changes to `Foo` but the one in `z2` remains as a different pet with name `Molly`.

This code doesn't compile, but I can't figure out why. I'm also unsure whether I need to have an explicit copy constructor to use for the binding of `__deepcopy__`, and whether I need to have a proper destructor.

*EDIT*: errors:

```
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13:
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12:
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../attr.h:14:
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:1472:16: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'enable_if_t<!std::is_void<Zoo>::value, Zoo>' (aka 'Zoo')
        return std::move(*this).template call_impl<remove_cv_t<Return>>(
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:291:59: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::detail::argument_loader<Zoo &>::call<Zoo, pybind11::detail::void_type, (lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14) &>' requested here
                (void) std::move(args_converter).template call<Return, Guard>(cap->f);
                                                          ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:143:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<(lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14), Zoo, Zoo &, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling>' requested here
        initialize(
        ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1616:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<(lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14), pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, void>' requested here
        cpp_function cf(method_adaptor<type>(std::forward<Func>(f)),
                     ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:50:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::class_<Zoo>::def<(lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14)>' requested here
        .def("__deepcopy__",
         ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:23:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument
    Zoo(Zoo& new_zoo){
    ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:18:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    Zoo() {}
    ^
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13:
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12:
In file included from /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../attr.h:14:
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:1504:16: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Zoo'
        return std::forward<Func>(f)(cast_op<Args>(std::move(std::get<Is>(argcasters)))...);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/cast.h:1472:42: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::detail::argument_loader<Zoo &>::call_impl<Zoo, (lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14) &, 0UL, pybind11::detail::void_type>' requested here
        return std::move(*this).template call_impl<remove_cv_t<Return>>(
                                         ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:291:59: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::detail::argument_loader<Zoo &>::call<Zoo, pybind11::detail::void_type, (lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14) &>' requested here
                (void) std::move(args_converter).template call<Return, Guard>(cap->f);
                                                          ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:143:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::cpp_function::initialize<(lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14), Zoo, Zoo &, pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling>' requested here
        initialize(
        ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1616:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function<(lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14), pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, void>' requested here
        cpp_function cf(method_adaptor<type>(std::forward<Func>(f)),
                     ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:50:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'pybind11::class_<Zoo>::def<(lambda at /Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:51:14)>' requested here
        .def("__deepcopy__",
         ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:23:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument
    Zoo(Zoo& new_zoo){
    ^
/Users/.../coding_experiments/pybind11/oop_docs/main.cpp:18:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    Zoo() {}
    ^
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: `Pet new_pet(t->get_name()); new_pets.push_back(&new_pet);` -- This will not work even if you got this to compile, as you are storing the address of a temporary inside the vector.

Comment: *This code doesn't compile* In this case please provide the compiler error(s) you get.

Comment: Why so much trouble? Using `Pet` by value instead of pointer saved you from so many lines of code. Everything you need will be implicitly defined.

Comment: @Red.Wave you mean having a vector of `Pet`s instead of pointers to them? This is just a toy example -- I mean to use this for a more complex object with more data.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate -- *I mean to use this for a more complex object with more data.* -- The amount of data does not determine whether the object is safely copyable as-is.  If your object does not contain any resources that need to be managed manually, then you don't need to use pointers.  And in any event, if the object did need to manage memory or a resource, then that object should have a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator and destructor already defined and tested.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Doesn't it matter for when I want to pass the entire vector of objects to a function?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate -- Your object could contain 50 `std::string's`, 25 `double`'s, 16 `int's`, 8 `std::vector<int>`'s and 22 `Widgets`.  As long as each of those types are safely copyable and assignable, then that entire object is safely copyable and assignable.

Comment: Also, if your intent was to "beat the compiler" at the optimization game by introducing pointers, that is a game you will more than likely lose.  The compiler is allowed to optimize copying and assignment, and is looking for patterns in the code that are well-recognized to facilitate the optimization step.  Introducing pointers will in many cases render the optimizer useless.  Add to that my initial comment: `Pet new_pet(t->get_name()); new_pets.push_back(&new_pet);` -- this does not work, as you must create an object that has a lifetime that outlives the local scope, and you didn't do this.

Comment: As long as you`re dealing with a collection of single type elements, pointer semantics doesn't make sense. Once you start going for dynamic polymorphism, then depending on the problem a variety of solutions come to mind. In short, you need to specify more details.

Comment: I was going to write a comment that none of these suggestions apply to pybind11 (since Python is a reference based language), but it seems pybind11 can handle all of that by itself, so your `Zoo` should indeed hold `std::vector<Pet>` and default copy constructor will do the trick then: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#deepcopy-support

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's fair -- coming from a C background, I thought pointers were the right answer for when I'd need to pass the vector into a function, but then the whole point is to not have to pass it to a function because we have object methods.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Oh, that makes sense! I was assuming that copy and deepcopy wouldn't be necessary if I had a vector of objects instead of a vector of pointers to objects, but then that vector is seen as a list on Python's side, so...